# Best way to clear a each list in a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a nested list like this

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
li = [list_1, list_2]
```

How do I clear each item in `li` so that `list_1` and `list_2` also become empty. I'm expecting something like:

```
print(li) # Output: [[],[]]
print(list_1) # Output: []
print(list_2) # Output: []
```

I tried

```
for i in range(len(parameters)):
        parameters[i] = []
```

but it doesn't clear `list_1` and `list_2`

Comment: don't modify collections while iterating over them. Also: what is `parameters` ?

Comment: What output do you expect for `list_3 = [[[1]], [2]]` ?

Comment: @JacobIRR OP is not modifying the collection, but the elements in the collection, which is totally okay, in fact, necessary sometimes, otherwise how could I, say, square all the numbers in my list of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `list.clear` method to empty the lists in-place and have that effect the original variables. By only assigning empty lists in their place, the original variables are not modified since you are creating new lists:

```
for p in parameters:
    p.clear()
```

which is equivalent to, but a better and more Pythonic version of:

```
for i in range(len(parameters)):
    parameters[i].clear()
```

An addition from @ShadowRanger's comment:

> As a small addendum, `del p[:]` is equivalent to `p.clear()`, and has been supported for longer. At this point, no version of Python without `list.clear` is supported (the `.clear` and `.copy` methods were added in 3.3 for symmetry with `set` and `dict`, even though sequences could do the same operations with `del seq[:]` and `seq[:]` already), and I agree `p.clear()` is more self-documenting, but it's worth pointing out that the other approach exists (`p[:] = ()` is also equivalent, but even less explicit than `del p[:]`), since you'll see it in older code.

Comment: I'd emphasize the clear loop over the OP's unPythonic `for i in range(len(parameters)):` loop.

Comment: Awesome, up-voted post-edit. As a small addendum, `del p[:]` is equivalent to `p.clear()`, and has been supported for longer. At this point, no version of Python without `list.clear` is supported (the `.clear` and `.copy` methods were added in 3.3 for symmetry with `set` and `dict`, even though sequences could do the same operations with `del seq[:]` and `seq[:]` already), and I agree `p.clear()` is more self-documenting, but it's worth pointing out that the other approach exists (`p[:] = ()` is also equivalent, but even less explicit than `del p[:]`), since you'll see it in older code.